# Cordova app status bar image notification

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build an android app using Cordova. Is there any plugin to show an image notification in the status bar.

Not icons but full image like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L75VU.jpg

Comment: Hi, have you finally found something?

Answer (score 0):

If your app also needs to record GPS data in the background, then try this plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation

You have the option to add an image/icon and various other notification settings for when the app is in the background:

```
option.notificationTitle
option.notificationText
option.notificationIcon
option.notificationIconColor
```

If you don't want or need background GPS, then I haven't seen a plugin that has that functionality so far.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @SuryaK Ah, I have no idea how you'd do that, sorry! That looks like it might be a custom native Java type thing.